# How to include only one class from aws-sdk in Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

In an effort to improve cold start latency in AWS Lambda, I am attempting to include only the necessary classes for each Lambda function. Rather than include the entire SDK, How can I include only the DynamoDB portion of the SDK?

```
// Current method:
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

// Desired method:
var AWSdynamodb = require('aws-dynamodb-sdk');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is: you do not need to do this.

The AWS SDK for JavaScript uses dynamic requires to load services. In other words, the classes are defined, but [the API data is only loaded when you instantiate a service object](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/service.js#L22-L28), so there is no CPU overhead in having the entire package around.

The only possible cost would be from disk space usage (and download time), but note that Lambda already bundles the `aws-sdk` package on its end, so there is no download time, and you're actually using less disk space by using the SDK package available from Lambda than using something customized.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible.
The npm registry only has aws-sdk. https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

There may be other npm packages available for dynamodb, but I would advice only using the sdk provided by aws team.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to instantiate the SDK outside of the handler.

This example is good, and will result in a cold start time of about 1s

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const SNS = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
   //do stuff
};
```

This example is bad and will result in a cold start time of about 5s

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
   const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
   const SNS = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'});
   //do stuff
};
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html

> Take advantage of execution context reuse to improve the performance
>   of your function. Initialize SDK clients and database connections
>   outside of the function handler, and cache static assets locally in
>   the /tmp directory. Subsequent invocations processed by the same
>   instance of your function can reuse these resources. This saves
>   execution time and cost.